# Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alarm_clock.v(133) near text "and"; expecting ")"

Tags: system-verilog

I keep getting this error and I tried all sorts of ways to fix it, but it doesn't help me.

I hope some one could help me in this.

The code snippet that has problem is below:

```
if((HR == AHR) and (MIN == AMIN)) To be exact.

always @ (posedge CLK)
begin
case(state)
NORMAL: begin
        DHR <= HR;
        DMIN <= MIN;
        if(ALON)
            begin
            AENABLED <= 1;

            if((HR == AHR) and (MIN == AMIN))
                begin
                ALARM <= 1;
                if(SNOOZE) // we assume that SNOOZE is to be operated only when the Alarm is ON!
                    begin
                    AMIN <= AMIN + 2;
                    if(AMIN == 60)
                        begin
                        AMIN <= 0;
                        AHR <= AHR + 1;
                            if(AHR == 24)
                                AHR <= 0;
                        end
                    else if(AMIN == 61) // since AMIN is incremented by 2 it can either be 60 or 61 depending on previous alarm time
                        begin
                        AMIN <= 1;
                        AHR <= AHR + 1;
                            if(AHR == 24)
                            AHR <= 0;
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
```

Answer (score 3):

`and` is not verilog! Try `&&` instead.

Comment: Okey, it works! Thank you.. there a few other minor errors like that. But this one is solved. 
Thankyou :)

Comment: `and` is a reserved keyword used for gate instances.